# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS font rendering problem with Firefox

Tags: fonts

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and when I open Firefox browser the font rendering is very bad, to the extent that is pretty much unusable. See screenshot below. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: If you right-click and **Inspect Element** it should give you more information. Some Mozilla fonts are installed in multiple locations and can wigg out so do you see this on other web pages ? Try some newspaper websites.

Comment: Try to reset fonts cache `sudo fc-cache -fv`

Comment: It happens with all web sites, including newspapers. Chrome works fine

Comment: Resetting the fonts does not work sadly.

Comment: Looks like antialiasing is turned off. Have you looked in font settings to see what it's set to? Have you looked in `about:config` for font antialiasing settings?

Comment: antialiasing is ON

Comment: Did you install firefox as snap, or is it deb package?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **antialiasing** is turned off. Look in font settings to see what it's set to.

Also look in about:config for font antialiasing settings.

If that's not the problem try create a new profile